# Regex returns some of the results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have put this together getting help from other SO answers. With this I get `["__COL__", "COL"]`, what I want to get is `["COL", "COL_ID"]`. What is the proper regex to use?

```
var myString = "this is a __COL__ and here is a __COL_ID__";
var myRegexp = /__([A-Z]+)__/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match);  // ["__COL__", "COL"]
```

Comment: If you read [some `exec()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) you'll see that your current result is because `.exec()` returns an array containing "the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured". Your regex doesn't match "COL_ID" at all because you don't allow underscore characters except at the beginning and end.

Comment: @nnnnnn, the main issue was I couldn't get `COL_ID` in the results; but, informative comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just including only uppercase alphabets, and missing the `_`. So, the RegEx becomes like this [`/__(\[A-Z_\]+)__/g`](http://regex101.com/r/tJ6fV5). And [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function returns only the first match, so, we have to `exec` again and again till it returns `null`.

[`exec` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description),

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured.

In our case, the first value would be the entire matched string, the second value would be the captured string. So, we are pushing only `match[1]` in the `result`.

```
var myString = "this is a __COL__ and here is a __COL_ID__";
var myRegexp = /__([A-Z_]+)__/g, match = myRegexp.exec(myString), result = [];
while (match) {
    result.push(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'COL', 'COL_ID' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W856u/3/)):

```
var myString = "this is a __COL__ and here is a __COL_ID__";
var myRegexp = /([A-Z]+_[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+)(?=__)/g;
var match = myString.match(myRegexp);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: That's totally wrong. You're ignoring the delimiter and just matching *any* capital letters. If your test string were `"This is a __COL__ and here is a __COL_ID__"`, you'd get very wrong results.

Comment: @meager Great point. Could potentially add the delimiter in a positive lookahead, as shown in the edit above.  However, depending on what the OP has as the string, it would also match **COL** in **COL__**.

Comment: Yes, that's really not good enough. You're now only matching half the delimiters.